# Нужна помощь в понятие задачи Java

Tags: java

Создать класс NumParser, и добавить в него статичный 
метод parse.
Это метод должен принимать класс из которого нужно вызывать метод valueOf,
и строку которая содержит число для парсинга.

Сигнатура метода parse:
public static  M parse(Class type, String value)

type - класс, из которого нужно вызывать метод valueOf
value - строка для парсинга
Я не могу понять что нужно сделать подскажите пожалуйста
я сделал так

```
public class NumParser {

    public static <M> M parse(Class<? extends Number> type, String value) {
        return (M) Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. метод(ы) `valueOf` статичны. А значит Generic-ами тут не воспользуешься. Есть мысли на счет использования рефлексии. При помощи нее найти метод и вызвать его.

```
public class NumParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parse(Integer.class, "10")); // результат 10
        // Ошибка. Класс String не наследуется от Number
        // System.out.println(parse(String.class, "10")); 
    }

    public static <T extends Number> T parse(Class<T> type, String value) {
        try {
            Method method = type.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            return type.cast(method.invoke(null, value));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```